# SQL Query fron AppMaker datasource

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Suppose we have a table `mealbookingtable` to store all meal booking made. We also have `foodItem` table to store all available food item. What we are trying to achieve is that to remove any food item that had already been booked on that specific flight date and flight no., hence the form will just show any food that had not yet booked for that date and flight no. The logic look almost like following and the return wil be display to the drop-down widget.

```
var checkfood = 
    select fooditem from mealbookingtable 
    where flightdate = <flightdate>
    and flightno = <flightno>;

if (checkfood === null){
    //return all food item list to dropdown widget
} else {
    //exclude fooditem from food item list
    //only then return the food item list to dropdown widget
}
```

Following is how the form looks like to give better understanding about it where the `<fligthdate>` & `<fligthno>` are parameters passed from the form widget.

[image]

I am not really sure whether we can do this and how to accomplish this in AppMaker but if anyone had any idea and mind to share some syntax that can be used in the server script that will be just great!

Comment: Give us your code, did you try something ? You tagged SQL, so what sql have you done so far ?

Comment: no I don't really know how to do/write the SQL on the AppMaker script ;(

Comment: but that basically is the logic in which I believe in normal SQL will do